# How to retrieve multiple issues on github graphql api (using javascript)?

Tags: javascript, api, github, graphql

The goal I want to achieve is to read and later write **issues** and **labels** within a github repository using javascript.

So far I have been able to get authenticated and retrieve some data on the repository, but I do not find the way to retrieve data neither on one single, nor on a set of issues.

This is the code I am using.

```
var request = require("request");

var url = 'https://api.github.com/graphql';
var headers = {
    Authorization:'token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'request',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

var options = {
  method: 'post',
  body: undefined,
  json: true,
  url: url,
  headers: headers
};


function makeRequest(options){ 
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.error('error posting json: ', error);
        throw error;
      }
      var responseHeaders = response.headers;
      var statusCode = response.statusCode;
      console.log('Status code: ', statusCode);
      console.log('Body: ', body);
    });
};

options.body = {
query: '{repository(owner:"TonyEdelweiss", name:"hello-world") {createdAt name projectsUrl}}'
};
makeRequest(options);

options.body = {
query: '{repository(owner:"TonyEdelweiss", name:"hello-world"){issues(first: 2){edges{cursor node{id}}}}}'
};
makeRequest(options);
```

On the first makeRequest() I get the following, which is okay:

> Status code:  200 Body:  { data:     { repository: 
>         { createdAt: '2017-09-29T17:01:25Z',
>           name: 'hello-world',
>           projectsUrl: 'https://github.com/TonyEdelweiss/hello-world/projects' } } }

On te second one I only get an '[Object]'  )-:

> Status code:  200 Body:  { data: { repository: { issues: [Object] } }
>   }

Can anybody give a hint?

Also I have found this in github API v4 documentation: "All GraphQL operations must specify their selections down to fields which return scalar values to ensure an unambiguously shaped response." This might explain why I am not getting the data, but gives no further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is actually working fine. But the maximum depth you can view using `console.log` default to 2. You can use [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to change it, set the depth to `null` to view the full object :

```
const util = require('util');

.....

console.log('Body: ', util.inspect(body, {depth: null}));
```